# How to prevent alert() flood?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script alerts once when user all scrolled down to bottom.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        alert();
    }
});
```

It works almost on all browsers, However, Internet Explorer alerts 3-4 times. My question is, what is the correct way to prevent that flood ?

Comment: Simple answer; don't user `alert()`. Longer answer, show/hide a div element when the scroll reaches the required point.

Comment: I dont use alert(). Its just an example to show that IE pushes multiply the function there.

Comment: what is the actual point of an empty alert, and what is the reasoning behind alert in this case?

Comment: your question is "how to prevent alert() flood" ... and you say "I don't use alert" ... then, you have no alert flood to deal with ... so, what is it you are actually asking?

Comment: @JaromandaX, what is the reason for asking the reason behind it, I am asking a question here to find an answer.

Comment: you prevent alert flood by not using alert as alert serves little to no purpose in modern javascript - I should post that as an answer, as it answers the question you posted

Comment: `what is the reason for asking the reason behind it, I am asking a question here to find an answer` - what is the purpose of asking a question for code you do not use? One purpose of comments is to ask for more information when the question is too abstract or too poorly written. I've exercised my ability to ask for more information as the question you've asked is nowhere near clear enough, and as it stands, the answer is to avoid doing what you purport to be doing in the question itself

Comment: @user198989 I recommend you change the wording of the title and possibly parts of the question to remove the emphasis from the `alert` being the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use like this:

```
var alerted;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!alerted && $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        alert('alert');
        alerted = 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag:

```
var bottom = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        if (!bottom) {
            alert();
            bottom = true;
        }
    } else {
        bottom = false;
    }
});
```